# Creating a Google Sheets spreadsheet with developer metadata using the Sheets API

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I am interested in creating spreadsheets in Google Sheets programmatically. One of my requirements is that I will be able to write to and read from developer metadata associated with columns in the spreadsheet.

I am currently having trouble with creating Developer Metadata - either spreadsheet-level or associated with a specific portion of the sheet. When I send the request to [`create`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create) a new Spreadsheet, I am receiving a successful response, and the created spreadsheet's metadata object. However, the object that is returned from this request does not include any metadata objects (as the API documentation suggests).

Setting an explicit metadata ID for the metadata entry and then attempting to retrieve it also does not appear to work (as you will see below).

Here is the JSON payload I have been sending with the request (I have been sending the request using the [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/) most recently, as well, to isolate it from my code):

```
{
  "properties": {
    "title": "test 6:19 with sheet metadata"
  },
  "sheets": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "sheetId": 0,
        "title": "Sheet1",
        "index": 0,
        "sheetType": "GRID",
        "gridProperties": {
          "rowCount": 2,
          "columnCount": 2
        }
      },
      "data": [REMOVED_FOR_SPACE],
  "developerMetadata": [
    {
      "location": {
        "spreadsheet": true,
        "locationType": "SPREADSHEET"
      },
      "metadataKey": "questionId",
      "metadataValue": "12345",
      "visibility": "DOCUMENT",
      "metadataId": 12345
    }
  ]
}
```

This request receives a 200, and returns a spreadsheet object that is missing any developer metadata, as mentioned before. The spreadsheet is created as described, and accessible via the UI.

I suspected that the response may just not include the metadata, despite the documentation. However, if I query the spreadsheet for the metadata ID above, I receive the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "No developer metadata with ID 12345.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

Comment: Related q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51315884/create-a-new-google-sheet-with-row-or-column-groups and the Bug Report that its OP filed: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111423856

Answer (score 4):

I had faced the same issue and I had totally given up on this. Later, I tried the "batchUpdate" API provided under **spreadsheet**. One of the "kind" field under "[Requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request)" takes the value - **createDeveloperMetadata**.

It takes the [CreateDeveloperMetadataRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#CreateDeveloperMetadataRequest) object whose structure is same as the one you tried providing while creating the spreadsheet.

On executing this with a random integer as Metadata Id, I got a `200 Response`. Further, performing a `GET` on developer Metadata, it returned me the correct response!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! In the end, I ended up going about things a different way and avoided using Sheet metadata completely. If I need to use metadata in the future this will be very helpful, though!