# Create a new Google Sheet with row or column groups

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm trying to create a new spreadsheet using [`spreadsheets#create`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create), with specified row groups.

In the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/sheets.spreadsheets.create), I am entering in the JSON below. which corresponds to the following appearance:

[image]

No errors are flagged or returned when I execute the call, but when the sheet is created, the specified grouping is not created - only the values are set.

```
{ "properties": {
    "title": "Test Spreadsheet",
    "locale": "en"
  },
  "sheets": [
    { "properties": {"title": "Test1"},
      "data": [
        {
          "startRow": 0,
          "startColumn": 0,
          "rowData": [
            { "values": [
                { "userEnteredValue": { "stringValue": "Top1" } }
              ]
            },
            { "values": [
                { "userEnteredValue": { "stringValue": "Top2" } }
              ]
            },
            { "values": [
                { "userEnteredValue": { "stringValue": "" } },
                { "userEnteredValue": { "stringValue": "Top2A" } }
              ]
            },
            { "values": [
                { "userEnteredValue": { "stringValue": "" } },
                { "userEnteredValue": { "stringValue": "Top2B" } }
              ]
            },
            { "values": [
                { "userEnteredValue": { "stringValue": "" } },
                { "userEnteredValue": { "stringValue": "Top2C" } }
              ]
            },
            { "values": [
                { "userEnteredValue": { "stringValue": "Top3" } }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "rowGroups": [
        { "range": {
            "dimension": "ROWS",
            "startIndex": 2,
            "endIndex": 5
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Even when I create the `rowGroups` JSON directly on the page, with its structured editor to make sure it is properly defined, the created spreadsheet still doesn't group the specified rows.  I have triple-checked all my objects from the top down, and can't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Also in my environment, both ``rowGroups`` and ``columnGroups`` cannot be used for "spreadsheets.create" using the request body like yours. So I add the groups using "spreadsheets.batchUpdate" after it created the spreadsheet. Although I had thought that I might occur for only my environment, I thought that this might be a bug or the specification, by your question.

Comment: @Tanaike Yeah as a workaround I'm actually trying to add them using batchUpdate, using addDimensionGroup to create the group and updateDimensionGroup to collapse the group, but I get an error on the second request "Invalid requests[1].updateDimensionGroup: dimensionGroup.depth must be \u003e 0" despite the fact that i pass depth:0 in the proper place.  (ARGH!!!)

Comment: Can you provide the request body of batchUpdate?

Comment: @Tanaike I [created a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51316212/collapsing-a-group-using-google-sheets-api) dealing with this new difficulty which provides this info.

Comment: Even if you drop all the values and extra bits - specifying solely the `rowGroups` - they won't get created. So yes, that's a bug with the implementation. Consider opening a Bug Report on the Sheets API Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:191608

Comment: The bug report is here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111423856  Please **star** it if you have the same issue.