# Collapsing a group using Google Sheets API

Tags: google-sheets-api

So as a workaround to [difficulties creating a new sheet with groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51315884/creating-a-new-google-sheet-with-pre-defined-groups) I am trying to create and collapse these groups in a separate call to [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate).  I can call request an `addDimensionGroup` successfully, but when I request `updateDimensionGroup` to collapse the group I just created, either in the same API call or in a separate one, I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid requests[1].updateDimensionGroup: dimensionGroup.depth must be \u003e 0",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

But I'm passing depth as 0 as seen by the following JSON which I send in my request:

```
{
    "requests":[{
          "addDimensionGroup":{
            "range":{
                "dimension":"ROWS",
                "sheetId":0,
                "startIndex":2,
                "endIndex":5}
            }
        },{
         "updateDimensionGroup":{
           "dimensionGroup":{ 
               "range": {
                   "dimension":"ROWS",
                   "sheetId":0,
                   "startIndex":2,
                   "endIndex":5
               },
               "depth":0,
               "collapsed":true
           },
           "fields":"*"
        }
    }],
    "includeSpreadsheetInResponse":true}',
   ...
```

I'm not entirely sure what I am supposed to provide for "fields", the documentation for [UpdateDimensionGroupRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateDimensionGroupRequest) says it is supposed to be a string ("string ( FieldMask format)"), but the [FieldMask definition itself](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.FieldMask) shows the possibility of multiple paths, and doesn't tell me how they are supposed to be separated in a single string.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You want to add the group and collapse the rows. If my understanding is correct, I think that your request body is almost correct. So how about modifying from ``"depth":0,`` to ``"depth":1,``? https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#DimensionGroup If this result was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is actually instructing you that the `dimensionGroup.depth` value must be `> 0`:

[image]

If you call `spreadsheets.get()` on your sheet, and request only the `DimensionGroup` data, you'll note that your created group is actually at depth `1`:

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{SSID}?fields=sheets(rowGroups)&key={API_KEY}
```

[image]

This makes sense, since the depth is (per API spec):

> **depth** *number*
> The depth of the group, representing how many groups have a range that wholly contains the range of this group.

Note that any given particular `DimensionGroup` "wholly contains its own range" *by definition*.

If your goal is to change the status of the `DimensionGroup`, then you need to set its `collapsed` property:

```
{
  "requests": 
  [
    {
      "updateDimensionGroup": 
      {
        "dimensionGroup": 
        {
          "range": 
          {
            "sheetId": <your sheet id>,
            "dimension": "ROWS",
            "startIndex": 2,
            "endIndex": 5
          },
          "collapsed": true,
          "depth": 1
        },
        "fields": "collapsed"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For this particular [`Request`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateDimensionGroupRequest), the only attribute you can set is `collapsed` - the other properties are used to identify the desired `DimensionGroup` to manipulate. Thus, specifying `fields: "*"` is equivalent to `fields: "collapsed"`. This is not true for the majority of requests, so specifying `fields: "*"` and then omitting a non-required request parameter is interpreted as "Delete that missing parameter from the server's representation".

To change a `DimensionGroup`'s `depth`, you must add or remove other `DimensionGroup`s that encompass it.